# Execute Stored Procedure from Stored Procedure w/ dynamic SQL capturing output

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Inside a stored procedure (A) I need to call a stored procedure (X) inside a specific database and capture the output. X returns a single value.

From what I understand I need to provide the DB name of X to the stored procedure in A and I need to use dynamic SQL to build the query on execution targeting the desired database.

What am unable to figure out is how to capture output from X in A to work with the result.

Comment: You should be able to do this using `sp_executesql` something like `EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC @rtn = ' + @db + N'.dbo.[your_stored_procedure] @output OUTPUT', N'@rtn AS INT, @output AS INT OUTPUT', @yourlocalvar1 = @rtn, @yourlocalvar2 = @output`, this is just off the top of my head, might need some adjustment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `sp_executesql` to dynamically call your nested Stored Procedure.

```
DECLARE @db AS SYSNAME
DECLARE @return_value AS INT
DECLARE @output_value AS INT
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Set your DB name
SET @db = N'mydb'

/*
Use sp_executesql to dynamically pass in the db and stored procedure
to execute while also defining the values and assigning to local variables.
*/
SET @sql = N'EXEC @rtn = ' + @db + '.dbo.[your_stored_procedure] @output OUTPUT'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
   , N'@rtn AS INT, @output AS INT OUTPUT'
   , @return_value = @rtn
   , @output_value = @output OUTPUT
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer lead me to a working implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer, following is the way to call stored procedures dynamically by passing parameters.

```
    DECLARE @SpName VARCHAR(1000)          
    SELECT @SpName = DeleteLiveSP FROM dbo.ArchivalInfo (NOLOCK) WHERE TableName = @TableName          


    DECLARE @SqlString nvarchar(2000)        
    DECLARE @ParamDef nvarchar(2000)        

    SET @SqlString = N'exec '+@SpName + ' @CriteriaParam'        
    SET @ParamDef = N'@CriteriaParam XML' 


    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SqlString ,@ParamDef, @CriteriaParam = @Criteria
```